# Chrome not rendering stylesheets served by Python/WebApp2

Tags: python, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer-8, webapp2

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

I am using Twitter Bootstrap with a basic page for a front end and serving everything with Python / WebApp2 (Not Google App Engine) in the back end.

If I load the page from the server in Internet Explorer 8, the styles appear.

If I load the page from C:/ in Chrome, the styles appear.

If I load the page from the server in Chrome, the styles do not appear.

I've checked all my mime types, compared the C:/ and server pages and everything looks the same.

I cannot for the life of me figure out why Chrome isn't rendering the style sheets when served by Python / WebApp2.

I can't figure out how to put code without it actually processing in this text box, so the page I'm using is basically the same as the example shown here:
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/getting-started.html

Any ideas?

Python Script for css
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tu4NX.png]

Non Styled - Served by Python / Webapp2 viewed in Chrome 
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfKIa.png]

Styled - Pulled from C viewed in Chrome

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/35C4S.png]

Non Styled - Chrome Resources Tab
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvQXt.png]

Styled - Chrome Resources Tab
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rel3r.png]

I am able to pull up CSS file in Chrome Resources tab and see contents of CSS file. No warnings that it is interpreted as text/xml in console.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gTUO.png]

Comment: Can you list the contents of the CSS file downloaded by Chrome from the server? My only other suggestion is to clear the cache in Chrome and try again.

Comment: I am able to see the contents of the CSS file through Chrome's resource tab. I edited the original question to address this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GAAAH I just figured it out!

In my python code about, you can see I am using 'self.response.headers.add_header'. I guess whenever you use the 'self.response.out.write' function, it has a 'text/html' content type by default. if you 'add headers' to that, then it adds a 'text/css' header before the final 'text/html' header. Chrome then reads the last header and uses this as the content type for the style shee. I guess IE and Opera use the first?
Anyways: to fix, use:

```
self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = "text/css"
```

and as a whole

```
def css(self, css_dir, filename, extension):
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = "text/css"
    self.response.out.write(open(css_dir + filename + extension,"rb").read())
```

Yay!

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer [using webapp templates](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/tutorials/gettingstarted/templates.html) over direct response HTML output from code.

just create index.html with

```
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{path_to_css}}" type="text/css" />
</head>
<!-- body.. -->
```

then You can set `path_to_css` from code. With this approach You can separate HTML,CSS from the code logic.